# What is the appropriate pattern for mapping multiple data sources to a single business object?

Tags: design-patterns

We have a business model and associated repository.  This is populated by disparate data from different tables in a database.  At some point, after the user had made changes to the data, we have to reflect those changes back to the database.  Currently this is done by associating the key with the object like this:

```
class DataObject 
{
    string SomeProperty;
    // more properties

    int Table1Id;
    int Table2Id;
    int Table3Id;
}
```

I proposed a slight cleanup by adding a property that identifies the source table, and then using a single "ExternalId" property; but I'm wondering if there is a better pattern for this that decouples the data and business layer better.

We are using C#, but this is a somewhat language agnostic question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you've made a mapping of the object model to the database model, now something has to actually execute the mapping, and you roughly have two choices: ***Active Record*** or ***Data Mapper***.

**Active Record**

When choosing a persistence strategy, the first decision you need to make is where to place the responsibility for carrying out the mapping. You have two very different options: you can either make each entity class itself responsible for the mapping, or you can use a completely separate class to do the mapping to the database.

The first option is known as the Active Record pattern: an object that wraps a row in a database table or view, encapsulates the database access, and adds domain logic on that data. An Active Record approach puts persistence methods directly onto the entity object. In this case, the Address class would probably have methods like Save, Update, and Delete, as well as a static Load method that queries the database for an Address object.

The typical usage of the Active Record pattern is to essentially make a strongly typed class wrapper around a single row in a database table. As such, the Active Record classes are generally an exact mirror of the database structure (this will vary between tools). Many Active Record implementations will generate the entity objects directly from the database structure.

**Data Mapper**

Nice as the Active Record pattern may be, it is often valuable to have an object structure that varies from the database model. You may want to map multiple classes to the same database table. You might have a legacy database schema that doesn't fit the shape of the objects that you would want to express in some business logic (a common occurrence for me on my last several projects).

This is where I would choose the Data Mapper pattern: a layer of mapper objects that move data between objects and a database while keeping them independent of each other and the mapper classes themselves. The Data Mapper pattern strips most of the responsibility of persistence from the entity objects in favor of classes external to the entities. With a Data Mapper pattern, you access, query, and save entity objects with some kind of repository .

**How do you choose between the two?**

Jeremy Miller in his article said :

" My personal bias is very strongly towards the Data Mapper solution. That aside, Active Record is best for systems with simpler domain logic, CRUD-intensive applications (create, read, update and delete, that is), and situations where the domain model doesn't need to diverge much from the database structure. Active Record may be more comfortable for many .NET development teams because it implies a datacentric way of working that is more common for .NET teams and, frankly, much better supported by .NET itself. I would characterize most persistence tools in the .NET space as Active Record tools.

On the other hand, Data Mapper is more appropriate for systems with complex domain logic where the shape of the domain model will diverge considerably from the database model. Data Mapper also decouples your domain model classes from the persistence store. That might be important for cases where you need to reuse the domain model with different database engines, schemas, or even different storage mechanisms altogether. "

**NOTE** : Most of these patterns were taken from Martin Fowler's book, Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture. I highly recommend reading this book if you have anything to do with writing enterprise applications.

For more informations check Jeremy Miller's [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569757.aspx#id0400008) .

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but I'm familiar with the two patterns and this doesn't answer my specific question, which is how to handle mapping multiple data sources to a single domain object.

Comment: @amnesia . You mean how to map many sources to single destination ?

Comment: Yes, we have a single business model that has data that could come from one of several different tables, when we need to write that data back, we have to be able to write it back to the original table.